# What does Add-Migration command use to compare schemas?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, code-first

I'm renaming several tables and columns. Since I don't want to lose the existing data, I created a migration from scratch.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "Providers", schema: "dbo", newName: "Vendors", newSchema: "dbo");
    migrationBuilder.RenameTable(name: "ProviderContacts", schema: "dbo", newName: "VendorContacts", newSchema: "dbo");
    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(name: "ProviderId", table: "AspNetUsers", newName: "VendorId", schema: "dbo");
    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(name: "ProviderId", table: "VendorContacts", newName: "VendorId", schema: "dbo");
    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(name: "ProviderId", table: "Locations", newName: "VendorId", schema: "dbo");
}
```

I then ran `Update-Database`. But this still leaves a bunch of indexes and foreign keys that should also be renamed. So I used the `Add-Migration` command to bring any remaining changes up to date.

But I notice the new migration seems to be dropping and recreating tables and columns that my custom migration already renamed.

```
migrationBuilder.DropTable(
    name: "ProviderContacts");

migrationBuilder.DropTable(
    name: "Providers");

migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
    name: "IX_Locations_ProviderId",
    table: "Locations");

migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
    name: "IX_AspNetUsers_ProviderId",
    table: "AspNetUsers");

migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
    name: "ProviderId",
    table: "Locations");

migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
    name: "ProviderId",
    table: "AspNetUsers");
```

My question is: What is the `Add-Migration` command comparing? Is it looking at the database or something else? Why didn't it recognize that these tables and columns have been renamed?

How can I get it to recognize the changes in my custom migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Core, `Update-Database` uses the `IMigrationsAssembly` service to discover migrations compiled into your assembly. It fetches the list of migrations that have been run against this database using another service. As the migrations are executed the list of migrations are updated in a table. The process doesn't know or care about the state of your database model, it doesn't cause any change in your database model. The process is designed to work against other databases, without any knowledge of your development environment.

Running `Add-Migration` uses the `IMigrationsAssembly` service to load the previous `ModelSnapshot` that has been compiled into your assembly, and the model from your contexts `OnModelCreating` method. Then it uses the `IMigrationsModelDiffer` service twice to compare the two models and produce the Up and Down migration routines. The new migration and `ModelSnapshot` is then serialised back into source code and written to disk. This process knows nothing about the state of any database, or the list of operations in previous migrations.

In other words, `Add-Migration` doesn't care that you've written another migration. It's still going to compare these two models. The migration differ isn't perfect, if the before and after tables are too different it will generate drop & create steps.

Another option is to perform one change at a time, creating new migrations for each step. Then merge the Up & Down methods into the last migration. And delete the rest.

Comment: Yes, I see the `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot` class now. I've removed my custom migration for now. Unfortunately, if I edit the migration, I don't see any way to apply it to the snapshot.

Comment: Calling Update-Database will execute the migration and save the snapshot

Comment: @Colin: As you can see above, it's not doing that. I renamed a table and column and ran `Update-Database`. But when I created a new migration, it's dropping and recreating the same table and column. So I can't see that it does update the snapshot.

Comment: @JonathanWood You have done 1.Add-migration 2.Edit migration 3.Update-Database (changes database and saves model as snapshot but the model is identical to the previous model because the code hasn't changed and now the snapshot and database no longer match) 4.Change model in code 5.Add-migration
The normal process is 1.Change the model in code 2.Add-migration 3.Edit migration to suit what you want to do (rename rather than drop) 4.Update-Database (model is stored as snapshot).So now you should delete the drop and recreate statements from the second migration and run Update-Database again.

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't use your actual database schema or the content of the migration files when it compares your C# model to the database model.

When you run your Update-Database Entity Framework serialises your C# model and stores it in the __MigrationHistory  table.

You have changed the name of the classes in the C# model then called Add-Migration so EF picks up that the model has changed and creates a migration to make the change.
If you don't like the way its doing the change or you need to update data to get the migration to work you can alter the migration it creates.

So normally you wouldn't create that initial migration before changing the C# classes. You should change the C# classes first. Then `Add-Migration` and change the generated migration so that when you call `Update-Database` it renames the tables rather than dropping them

In your current situation you could just delete the drop and recreate statements from the second migration since the renaming has already occurred

Comment: EF Core doesn't store the model in the database, it's compiled into a `ModelSnapshot` class.

Comment: I see. I have described how EF6 works. But the mechanism isn't so important. The point is that it doesn't care that you've written another migration. It's still going to compare the two models. So in the current situation I think the easiest solution is to delete the unwanted drop and recreate statements then Update-Database to store the new model in the snapshot

Comment: @Colin: I did run `Update-Database`. I indicated that in my question. So this is where the disconnect is for me.

Comment: @JonathanWood your question says that you called Update-Database after your first migration. You need to call Update-Database after your second migration too but you'll have to delete  the unwanted drop and recreate statements first